# Strange p-value

Tags: r, p-value

I have `to_compare` data.frame structure

```
id - int
genotype - Factor
group - num
```

And I have next data in `to_compare` data.frame

```
table(to_compare$group,to_compare$genotype)

      G/G
    1 165
    2 134
```

So, I have only G/G genotype in both groups (often I have 3 genotypes) with 165 samples in #1 group and 134 samples in #2 group.

I try to compare this two groups and get p-value

```
with(to_compare, chisq.test(table(group,genotype), simulate.p.value=T))

data:  table(group, genotype)
X-squared = 3.214, df = NA, p-value = 0.08346
```

**p-value = 0.08346** - it can't be true! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running `chisq.test` on table which is 2x1 (2 rows, 1 column).

See `?chisq.test`:

> If x is a matrix with one row or column, or if x is a vector and y is
>   not given, then a goodness-of-fit test is performed (x is treated as a
>   one-dimensional contingency table). The entries of x must be
>   non-negative integers. In this case, the hypothesis tested is whether
>   the population probabilities equal those in p, or are all equal if p
>   is not given.

This means that `chisq.test` is not comparing groups here. It tests if groups are of equal size.

Or, to be more strict: it treats group membership as random and tests if probabilty of being in each group equals 0.5.

Comment: so how can I compare any tables (2x1, 2x2, 2x3, 2x4 and etc.)?

Comment: There is no problem with 2x2, 2x3 and so on. `chisq.test` will handle them

Comment: For 2x1 there is nothing to compare: you have only G/G in both groups. It's like you tried to compare number of heads betweene men and women. It's nothing to compare: in both groups you have only one-headed creatures.

Comment: ok. i will be use if-else to check is table 2x1. Thanks